# How do I make a small sample solar cell?

Tags: solar-cell

I want to know how to make a sample solar cell which can generate power of a very small magnitude.  What material is required and how would I assemble it to make a simple solar cell?

Comment: How much time are you willing to invest, and what type of solar cell?

Comment: Copper Oxide solar cells can easily be made "at home'. Power out is utterly minimal - but they are a true photovoltaic device.

Answer (score 3):

Shining bright sunlight on an LED or any optical, junction device (photodiode etc.) will cause it to generate a very small amount of electricity - you might have a play with that phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

For my optoelectronics class final project, my group attempted to make a [nanocrystalline titanium dioxide solar cell](http://mrsec.wisc.edu/Edetc/nanolab/TiO2/index.html).  Short of having access to silicon fab equipment, I think this [dye-sensitized solar cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dye-sensitized_solar_cell) is the best you can do.

The (slightly) less-common materials it uses are:

- Tin-oxide-coated glass plates/slides
- Nanocrystalline TiO<sub>2</sub>
- Potassium iodide

Ours ended up failing, I believe it was because the consistency of our TiO<sub>2</sub> paste wasn't that good, or some possible shorts between the plates.  This seems to be a fairly common educational cell, and the [mechanism of action](http://www.chem.yale.edu/~cas/tio2.html) is well-described.